# Location of YII extension folder

Tags: yii, slider, directory

I am new with **YII framework**, and our problem is TO FIND THE *EXTENSION FOLDER* and we need a yii framerwork with a SLIDER.

Does anybiy know where the extension folder is?

Here is the [link for the instructions](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/slider/)

please see INSTALL corner.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the extension folder (in `yii1`) is located in :

```
  yourAppName\protected\extensions
```

I hope this is what you are looking for